# Playing A simple Video file,not working

Tags: android

I made a simple app to play video but the video is not played.I put the video file in res/raw folder.

```
public class Video extends Activity {

private MediaController mc;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    VideoView video = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video);

    Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "kidvideo");

    mc = new MediaController(this);
    video.setMediaController(mc);

    video.setVideoURI(uri);
    video.start();
}
```

}

---

I have changed the code so that I can run the video file from SD CARD. I have push-ed the video file in data/misc/video/ folder. and changed the code into -

```
public class Video extends Activity {

private MediaController mc;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 // Fill view from resource
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    VideoView video = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video);

 // Load and start the movie
    video.setVideoPath("data/misc/video/pocket-bike-kid");
    video.start();


}

}
```

but IT IS NOT WORKING.......

Answer (score 0):

You lack a '/' between the package name and the video Id.

Moreover, "kidvideo" wont work. You need to use R.raw.kidvideo

Comment: Yes, this URI is working-Uri uri = 
    Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() +"/"+R.raw.kidvideo);
The video is being played but I cant see any video,I can only listen the sound... WHY..

Comment: The video is lagging heavily..not showing well. Is the problem with the emulator? The emulator is set for Android 2.2(SD card-250 Mb,skin HVGA). Or the video file format ? The 3gp video is played well outside.

Comment: various possibilities. try on a real device to have an actual idea of the performances

Comment: I have changed the code so that I can run the video file from SD CARD. Ihave push ed the video file in data/misc/video/ folder. and changed the code into -
         // Fill view from resource
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        VideoView video = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video);
        
     // Load and start the movie
        video.setVideoPath("data/misc/video/pocket-bike-kid");
        video.start();